# hierarchical basis functions finite element

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method, poissons-equation, galerkin-methods

I am using the hierarchical basis functions on the reference element $[-1,1]$ which are 
$$\theta_1(\xi)=1/2(1-\xi) $$
$$\theta_2(\xi)=1-\xi^2$$
$$\theta_3(\xi)=1/2(1+\xi) $$
By using the Galerkin finite element method for the Poissson equation
$$u_h(x)=u(x_{i})(x_{i+1}-x)/h +u(x_{i+1/2})( 1-4((x-x_{i+1/2})/h)^2) + u(x_{i+1})(x-x_{i})/h$$ 
on $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$.

I am wondering if it is correct or not. I checked with the $u''=1$ which the exact solution is $u(x)=x/2(x-1)$.

For example checking $u(0.0113)=-0.0056$ on $[0,0.1]$ with h=0.1, where $u(0)=0,~u(0.05)=-0.02375,~u(0.1)=-0.045$. But $u_h(0.0113)=-0.0146$ which has the high error. What is the problem?

Comment: I would really appreciate if you also help me with this question. @knl

Comment: Care to elaborate how you arrived at this expression for $u_h$? I typically implement these methods by considering a reference element that is mapped to a global element. My approach does not give such an explicit expression for the discrete solution and thus it's hard for me to judge whether it is correct or not without a derivation.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is very helpful if you give me the approximation of $u_h(x)$ on $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ respect to the reference element functions. i.e. $\theta 1(\xi)$, $\theta 2(\xi)$ and $\theta 3(\xi)$

Comment: Here is writing $u_h$ respect the reference basis function $$u_h(x)=u_{i+1} (1/2 (1-\xi)) ~ + ~u_{i+1/2} (1-\xi^2)~ +~ u_i (1/2 (1+\xi))$$If you put $$\xi=2(x-x_{i-1})/h~-1$$ you can get the above formula. @knl

Comment: You might want to recheck the middle term. I get a slightly different looking expression after the substitution.

Comment: Here is the detail$$1 - {\xi ^2} = 1 - {(\frac{{2(x - {x_{i - 1}})}}{h} - \frac{{{x_i} - {x_{i - 1}}}}{h})^2} = 1 - {(\frac{{2x - ({x_{i - 1}} + {x_i})}}{h})^2} = 1 - {(\frac{{2x - 2{x_{i + 1/2}}}}{h})^2} = 1 - 4{(\frac{{x - {x_{i + 1/2}}}}{h})^2}$$